# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'Laptop1' for key 'products_name_unique'")

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5.6

This is My ProductsTableSeeder
I create the products into products table and relationship with cateogries
creating category_product table and adding foreign key to that.

I have an error when I migrate and seed the data it says duplicate.
How do I fix it?

```
use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class ProductsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //

        //Product::truncate();

        for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
            Product::updateOrCreate([
                'name'=> 'Laptop'.$i,
                'slug' => 'laptop'.$i,
                'details' => [13,14,15][array_rand([13,14,15])].'inch,'.[1,2,3][array_rand([1,2,3])].'TB SSD,32GB RAM',
                'price' => rand(1500,3000),
                'description' => 'Lorem'.$i.' ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fermentum. laoreet turpis, nec sollicitudin dolor cursus at. Maecenas aliquet, dolor a faucibus efficitur, nisi tellus cursus urna, eget dictum lacus turpis.',
                ])->categories()->attach(1);
        }
        $product = Product::find(1)-> categories()->attach(2); 
}
```

This is Product Table.

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('details')->nullable();
            $table->float('price');
            $table->text('description');
            //$table->integer('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is Category Table.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is relationship table.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Comment: is the table empty when you're running the seed? try `php artisan migrate:refresh` and then `php artisan db:seed`. Another thing to pay attention is that when you're attaching to categories 1 (inside the for) and 2 (after the for), those categories don't exist, you'll need to create those categories first if seeding from an empty database.

Comment: I tried them all

Comment: there was no errors running php artisan migrate:refresh I have this error when db:seed

Comment: ok, if you tried the refresh and still not working try the following: `php artisan migrate:refresh` then go to you database manager and do a `SELECT * FROM products;` let us know if the table is empty or not. Also let us know the down() methods on your migrations.

Comment: Now I have this error !Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a
foreign key constraint fails (`onetech`.`category_product`, CONSTRAINT `category_product_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) values
(1, 1))

Comment: that's because you're attaching the products to the category ID=1 when doing `->categories()->attach(1);` . And that category doesn't exist as you just refreshed the database. Before your foreach try adding the line `Category::create(['name'=>'Category1', 'slug'=>'cat1']);`

Comment: Finally I got it

Comment: Using method of restarting LoL

Comment: Thank you all :D

Comment: my bad actually...I didn't pay attention that you were using the `updateOrCreate()` function and the problem is that you're passing only one parameter. Check my answer, should do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error happens because the database isn't empty and you're not passing the attributes to the `updateOrCreate()` function. Therefore Laravel is trying to create a new one. [Check the API](https://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_updateOrCreate).

It should work fine if you just adjust your `updateOrCreate()` function to:

```
Product::updateOrCreate(['id' => $i], [
            'name'=> 'Laptop'.$i,
            'slug' => 'laptop'.$i,
            'details' => [13,14,15][array_rand([13,14,15])].'inch,'.[1,2,3][array_rand([1,2,3])].'TB SSD,32GB RAM',
            'price' => rand(1500,3000),
            'description' => 'Lorem'.$i.' ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas fermentum. laoreet turpis, nec sollicitudin dolor cursus at. Maecenas aliquet, dolor a faucibus efficitur, nisi tellus cursus urna, eget dictum lacus turpis.',
])->categories()->attach(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the existing tables and then running migrate.